# How to access img tag with the same name attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of images in HTML code:

```
<img name="image[]" />
<img name="image[]" />
<img name="image[]" />`
```

I want to access all of them when I click on them using JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: Which one of them, the first, second or third.

Comment: You can use [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) and then index to the desired image, or if your 'click' handler is on the `img` tag itself, you can just use `this` in the handler function to refer to the element that was clicked, which will be one of your `img` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('name="image\\[\\]"').on('click', function() {
    var this_one = this; // "this" is the clicked one
});
```

Without jQuery, it would be something like

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll('[name=image\\[\\]]');

for (var i=img.length; i--;) {
    img[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}

function handler() {
    // "this" is the clicked image
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8k2v5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("img[name='image\[\]']");

for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", someFunc, false);
}

function someFunc(e){
   // you can use the `elements` array to access them all
   // or simply the `this` for the particular element clicked on
   this.src = "http://placehold.it/400x400";
}
```

A pure JS solution.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7FQ64/)